# importing KernelDensity in Python2.7 and 3.2

Tags: python, pip, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn scikit using examples on the following page:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html#example-neighbors-plot-kde-1d-py

I have both Python2.7 and 3.2 installed on my machine(Ubuntu 12.04). When I try the following line in 2.7,

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
```

I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name KernelDensity
```

and when I run it in 3.2, I get the following error:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:33:50) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ball_tree import BallTree
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree (sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.c:34290)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

The version I have is:

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.15-git'
```

I have also run the following:

```
sudo -E pip install -U scikit-learn
```

and it returns:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I have recently been learning python, and as I make progress in understanding the language, I have begun to learn `sklearn' but with this error, I am stuck. How do I fix it?

In trying different options, I also upgraded numpy (to version 1.8.1), and after uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-learn using pip as suggested, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    pkgload(verbose=SCIPY_IMPORT_VERBOSE,postpone=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 177, in __call__
    for package_name in self._get_sorted_names():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 114, in _get_sorted_names
    for name in depend_dict.keys():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Try uninstalling your installed scikit-learn, then re-install using pip.

Comment: I just did that, and now I get a new error - just updated my post with it. I had upgraded numpy based on some googl'ing.